# Different license types for AppExchange app

Tags: appexchange, licenses, lma, feature-management, fma

We want to sell 2 different license types for our AppExchange app: Admin and User. The difference is that only an Admin can make changes to the custom metadata types that define the app configuration.

Since LMA doesn't seem to provide our desired level of granularity for defining different license types do we need to use the FMA (Feature Management App)? If yes, would it be correct to define a new Feature of type Integer called "Admin License Count"? The client can then check APP__IsAdmin__c on appropriate Users, and a User trigger enforces the count.

Does that work? If yes, are we reinventing the wheel? i.e. does LMA or FMA or COA (Channel Order App) have a solution to this?

Comment: Are you looking to charge these "license types" differently?

Comment: Yes. Each license type is priced differently.